# How do I order the solution of Solve?

Tags: equation-solving, sorting

How can I order the solutions of `Solve` from the one with the smallest real part to the one with the greatest real part?

Comment: `SortBy[Re@*Last]@solutions`?

Comment: @kglr exactly thanks

Comment: it seems that solutions returned by `Solve` are already sorted in the desired order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the output of `Solve` with `SortBy[Re @* Last]`.

However, I think `Solve` already returns solutions in the desired order (sorted by the real parts with ties broken  by the absolute values of their imaginary part).

Checking the conjecture using 1000 random polynomials:

```
SeedRandom[1]
polynomials = Table[TypeSystem`RandomPolynomial[], 1000];
solutions = DeleteCases[Solve[#[x] == 0., x] & /@ polynomials, {{}}];

solutions == SortBy[Re@*Last] /@ solutions
```

> True

Comment: I am considering a much more complicated expression containing continued fraction and the solution are not orderd in the correct way. If you want I can edit my post to add my expression